# Nancy fails to find static content in custom convention

Tags: nancy

I've set up a Nancy bootstrapper to serve static content from a non-default directory path (it's self hosted Nancy).

Strangely, the following works for the custom View location convention but not either of the js or css static content conventions (and yes, both files and folders exist at these locations!).  My attempts at trying to resolve this are further compounded as I haven't figured out how to log errors which occur when static content is not found.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Nancy;
using Nancy.Conventions;
using Nancy.Bootstrapper;
using Nancy.TinyIoc;

namespace MyApp
{
    public class ApplicationBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
    {

    private const string RELATIVE_PATH_TO_SOURCE = @"../static/MyApp/";

    protected override void ConfigureConventions(NancyConventions nancyConventions)
    {

        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("js", string.Concat(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_SOURCE, "Scripts/")));
        nancyConventions.StaticContentsConventions.Add(StaticContentConventionBuilder.AddDirectory("css", string.Concat(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_SOURCE, "Content/")));
        this.Conventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add((viewName, model, context) =>
        {
            return string.Concat(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_SOURCE, "Views/", viewName);
        });
        this.Conventions.ViewLocationConventions.Add((viewName, model, context) =>
        {
            return string.Concat(RELATIVE_PATH_TO_SOURCE, "Views/", context.ModuleName, "/", viewName);
        });

        base.ConfigureConventions(nancyConventions);
    }

    protected override IRootPathProvider RootPathProvider
    {
        get
        {
            return new MyRootPathProvider();
        }
    }

    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        pipelines.OnError += (ctx, ex) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("RootPath : {0}", DebugRootPathProvider.RootPath);
            Console.WriteLine("Unhandled error on request: {0} : {1}", ctx.Request.Url, ex.Message); //HACK
            Console.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace); //HACK poor man's logging
            return null;
        };
    }
}

public class MyRootPathProvider : IRootPathProvider
{
    public static readonly string RootPath;
    static MyRootPathProvider()
    {
        RootPath = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    }

    public string GetRootPath()
    {
        return RootPath;
    }
}
}
```

The output from Chrome and ProcMon is as follows:
[image: ProcMon output]
[image: Google Chrome output]

How should I:

1. Log errors occurring with not found js and css files?
2. Resolve the 404 errors with the static file conventions?

Comment: I'm thinking if you call the base `ConfigureConventions` *after* you change the conventions you'll find it resetting it...but that's just a guess.

Comment: I've tried `ConfigureConventions` in both locations, no luck either way.

Comment: It seems to be that Nancy is [designed not to serve static content outside of any child folders](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Tests/Unit/StaticContentConventionBuilderFixture.cs#L107), but it still doesn't explain as to why it would silently fail and not provide an error message.

Comment: How are you hosting the application? I had a similar problem using Nancy.Owin with Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb due to IIS not using the Owin handler for request paths containing dots - by default IIS will use the static file handler for anything with a dot in it. You can fix it by telling IIS to use Owin for all requests: `<add name="Owin" verb="*" path="*" type="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.OwinHttpHandler, Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" />`.

Comment: @mattk - perfect!  Solved for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Instead of logging you can use [sysinternals process monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) and look for what files the nancy process (exe or IIS worker process) are attempting to read.

Comment: Good call. And therein lies the stranger thing.  All operations are requesting css and js files from the correct Contents and Scripts directories, returning SUCCESS for all, but still a 404 in the browser...

Comment: I've added screenshots of both ProcMon and web inspector to the question.

Comment: Hrm, any first chance exceptions occurring in the output window? You can always step into the nancy code.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers, I've found [the reason](https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/master/src/Nancy.Tests/Unit/StaticContentConventionBuilderFixture.cs#L107)

Comment: @sprocketonline I guess theres something to be said for BDD.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems with serving static files (in my case js files) in a self host environment as well. They were not recognized at all, not even in the default "Content" folder. My solution: I installed the [Microsoft StaticFiles NuGet Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Owin.StaticFiles/).

In the startup class, register a static files folder like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.UseStaticFiles("/Scripts");
        app.MapSignalR();
        app.UseNancy();
    }
}
```

This way, all files and subfolders in the "Scripts" folder are served as static files. There is also an overload of the UseStaticFiles() function that lets you map a physical path to a virtual path.

Important here: the call to UseNancy() has to be the very last, otherwise everything after it won't work. I also tried to combine it with SignalR, as you can see above, and there the UseNancy() call had to be at the end as well.

Comment: This works for my setup (Nancy, Owin, self host with mono on linux).